# Почему - проворонить?

Tags: фразеология

Задумалась: интересно, слово "проворонить" пошло от басни Крылова или возникло не зависимо от нее. И, если так, то при чем тут ворона?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь интересны две точки зрения.

А. Из словаря Михельсона. Ворона! (иноск.) ротозѣй.
Ср. Ты околесину понесъ... Да чуть было и про то дѣло не проболтался... не толкни я тебя, ты бы такъ все ему и выложилъ... эхъ ты, ворона!
П. И. Мельниковъ. Въ лѣсахъ.

В этом случае полное соответствие с басней Крылова .
Ворона - проворонить, приставка ПРО придает значение "пропустить что-то, совершая действие, названное глаголом": проглядеть, прослушать.

Б. Скороговорка. "Стерегла цыплят Варвара, а ворона воровала, всех цыплят поворовала - проворонила Варвара".

Ворона не кажется глупой птицей, зато мы любим считать ворон. Может быть, Варвара их считала  и поэтому проворонила?

Answer (score 4):

Пошло, действительно, от басни, но не от Крылова: сюжет басни о Вороне и Лисице очень древний. Есть сведения, что он был известен ещё в древней Индии. Вместо лисы, правда, фигурировал хитрый шакал.Самый ранний из дошедших до нас вариантов - басня Эзопа(6 век до н.э.):"Ворон унёс кусок мяса и уселся на дереве. Лисица увидела, и захотелось ей заполучить это мясо. " Дальше идёт знакомая нам история. Мораль эзоповской басни имеет широкий смысл: "Басня уместна против человека неразумного".

Сюжет этот был использован также Федром, этот сюжет присутствует в опытах византийского писателя Игнатия Диакона (VIII-IX вв.) :

Ел ворон сыр; лиса хитрить пустилася: 
"Будь голос у тебя - ты стал великим бы! " 
Закаркал глупый, сыр из клюва выронив; 
А та: "Есть голос у тебя, да мозгу нет".

У Жана де Лафонтена (1621 -1695) "Ворон и лисица" имеет более развернутый сюжет. Начало вот какое:

Дядюшка ворон, сидя на дереве,
Держал в своём клюве сыр.
Дядюшка лис, привлечённый запахом,
Повёл с ним такую речь:
"Добрый день, благородный ворон! ".

В России у Крылова тоже были предшественники- В. К. Тредиаковский и А.П.Сумароков. Это Сумароков Ворона на Ворону заменил. Так что это именно баснописцы снизили величие образа Ворона,которого древние считали мудрым прорицателем, священной птицей.Вот пока молчит - мудрый, как рот откроет и закаркает - глупая ворона,ротозейка, неуклюжая, далеко не летающая, отвлекающаяся на всё, что блестит, и т.д.-это уже на русской почве такое неуважение.